# Finding all the common and sub common values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new in using dicitonaries in python. I have a simple Problem at Hand. I have dicrionary named "Input".

```
   Input={'VAR1':['K1','K2','K3','K4','K5...'],
'VAR2':['K3','K4',...],
'VAR3':['K2','K4','K5',...]}
```

The number of keys in the dictionary "Input" can vary. The Output i desire is to get a list of all common values and i want to get Sub common values as a dictionary

```
'K4' string common in all the lists (for all key values)
'K3' is only present in the list with key'VAR1' and 'VAR2'.
```

So it helps if i have the corresponding keys

Output:

```
Common_Value=['K4',....]

Subcommon_Values1=['VAR1':['K3....'],'VAR2':['K3....']]
Subcommon_values2=['VAR1':['K5',...],'VAR3':['K5',....]]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: How are you determining what are common and subcommon values, conceptually if not programmatically?

Comment: i would just check if the string 'K4' exists in all the list of values for all the keys

Comment: I want to find out the common most strings in all the value lists and write it out in a separate list and then the subcommon strings @ScottHunter

Comment: What distinguishes common from subcommon?

Comment: The common list should contain the values which are present in all the lists. as in the above example 'K4' string exists in all the value lists of the dicitionary... while the string 'K3' exists only in the 'VAR1' key value and 'VAR3' key value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you all of the common values:

```
sect = None
for k,v in Input.items():
    if sect == None:
        sect = set( v )
    else:
        sect = sect.intersection( set(v) )
Common_Value = list( sect )
```

Until you make clear what the difference between your different SubCommonValues results are, and their actual structure (you seem to have keys in lists), can't be sure this is what you want or not:

```
all = None
for k,v in Input.items():
    if all == None:
        all = set( v )
    else:
        all = all.union( set(v) )
diff = all.difference( sect )
uncom = { x:list() for x in diff }
for x in diff:
    for k,v in Input.items():
        if x in v:
            uncom[x].append(k)
grps = {}
for k,v in uncom.items():
    kv = tuple(v)
    if kv not in grps:
        grps[kv] = [k]
    else:
        grps[kv].append(k)
for k,v in grps.items():
    print({ x:v for x in k })
```

Comment: As in the example Output which i showed above. 'K3' exists in the list with key 'VAR1' and with 'VAR2' but is not present in the 'VAR3' list. So inorder to know where the 'K3' string is present i will be needing it a dictionary

Comment: sorry for the late reply. But when i run your snippet i get an Attribute error. i am using python 3.5

Comment: thanks for the Idea and your code. i chaned it a bit to suit my needs

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
result=[i for i in Input if "K4" in Input[i]]
```

Example :

```
>>> Input={'VAR1':['K1','K2','K3','K4','K5'],'VAR2':['K3','K5'],'VAR3':['K2','K4','K5']}
>>> result=[i for i in Input if "K4" in Input[i]]
>>> result
['VAR1', 'VAR3']
```

**EDIT** :

maybe something like :

```
commonValues=['K4', 'K2']
result=[i for i in Input if set(commonValues).issubset(set(Input[i]))]
```

this will return the list of `key` in your `Input` `dict` that contain all element of the `commonValues` list...

Comment: i tried that but i Need the common values to be in one list and the size of the lists can vary so i was not able to compare.

Comment: see Edit in my post